# WP Loop with custom array field as argument

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do a query with the arguments below. Somehow, WP just doesn't return any posts. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! Any help?

Some more info: I have a custom post type that contain featured images. I want them to be displayed in a header slider. Through Advanced Custom Fields plugin I've created a custom field in the posts: 'assigned_page'. It's an array with page ID's on which that specific slide should be displayed. '$current_page' is the ID of the current page that's to be displayed. So, $args should filter the custom post type, and the posts that have the current page ID in their 'assigned_page' array.

```
// Get the current page ID
global $post;
$current_page = $post->ID;
$string_page = (string)$current_page;
$current_parent_page = $mv_is_subpage->ID;

// Post selection

$args = array (
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
    'order'          => $order,
    'no_found_rows'  => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
                'meta_key' => 'assigned_page',
                'meta_value' => $string_page,
                )
            ),
    );
```

Then:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then the loop:

```
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be like this (according to docs at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) :

```
array(
            'key' => 'assigned_page',
            'value' => $string_page,
            )
```